# Python 2.7 global variables?

Tags: python, sockets

I have some code which attempts to write to a socket (ardSocket), and if it throws an exception it will try to reconnect. I declared the socket variable as global so that when assigned in the separate function, it should still be accessible to the rest of the program, but for some reason still throws an exception. When I declare the actual socket globally at the beginning of the code, everything works fine. Why can't I declare  ardSocket=None globally, then assign it for use in a separate function?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
Arduino LED values: 0=down, 1=up, 2=blink
'''
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import serial
import time

ardSocket = None

def ardConnect():
    arduinoFound=False

    while arduinoFound==False:
        try:
            ardSocket=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)
            arduinoFound=True
            print "Arduino connected"
        except:
            print "Arduino not found. retrying in 10 seconds"
            time.sleep(10)

while 1==1:
    response=Popen(['ping','-c 1','google.com'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
    stdout,nothing=response.communicate()

    if "Name or service not known" in stdout:               #If DNS fails
        try:
            ardSocket.write('0')                                #Solid RED LED
        except:
            ardConnect()

    else:
        pingTestArray=stdout.splitlines()                   #Split ping output into array by lines
        pingTestArrayList=pingTestArray[4].split(" ")       #Split the line containing packet loss by words
        packetLoss=pingTestArrayList[5].replace('%','')     #Remove the % from the element containing packet loss number
                                                            #and assign value to packetLoss var


        if int(packetLoss) > 30 and int(packetLoss) < 95:   #If packet loss > 30% && < 95% warn, FLASH RED LED
            try:
                ardSocket.write('2')
            except:
                print "ard error"
                ardConnect()
        elif int(packetLoss) > 94:                          #Network is down, >95% packet loss, SOLID RED LED
            try:
                ardSocket.write('0')
            except:
                print "ard error"
                ardConnect()
        else:
            try:
                ardSocket.write('1')                            #Else show good, GREEN LED
            except:
                print "ard error"
                ardConnect()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: `ardConnect` is assigning to a local. It doesn't matter that a global with the same name exists.

Comment: You have forgotten to declare `ardSocket` global in your function, therefore it's local in the function where it's assigned.

Comment: Even if I do: global ardSocket

it still errors.

Comment: Ahh I got it, thank you. I had to declare it as global inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by declaring the variable global inside the function. Thanks to the comments/help.